# How to express one thing is more important than another?

Tags: idiom

How to express that one thing is more important in Latin? As an example, voice of the people over voice of the king can be stated in Latin as *Vox populi supra vox regis*. I interested in expressing things like "family is more important than work".

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you explain where you want to use this expression? You tagged the question as [tag:legal-latin], so are you only interested in legal situations? Or do you want to be able to say things like "family is more important than work"? You can edit your question to add details. (Try explaining in English, but if you are not sure whether you got it right, you can also add an explanation in another language. Someone else can help you translate it more fluently.)

Comment: I'm sorry if put the tag incorrectly. I didn't what the correct tag for my question. Your example "family is more important than work" is what i'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I took the liberty to edit your question a bit to clarify it. Feel free to make any further edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two ways to say "X is more important than Y":

1. *X plus valet quam Y*. (Literally: "X is stronger than Y.")
2. *X maioris momenti/gravitatis/ponderis est quam Y.* (Literally: "X is of more weight or importance than Y.")

In both of these the words X and Y are in the nominative.
For plurals you need to pluralize the verbs (*valent*, *sunt*).
The verb *est* or *sunt* can be left out.

It is also possible to say "X is above Y" as you suggest.
In that case Y should be in accusative.
In your example the genitives "of the people" and "of the king" stay in genitive: *populi*, *regis*.
It should be *vox populi [est] supra vocem regis*.
The verb *est* can be left out, but it is still understood to be there.

Comment: @OldSport19 I'm glad to be able to help! Now that you have gotten some reputation from votes on your question, you can vote questions and answers you like. And when you always accept the most useful answer to a question you asked yourself by ticking the green check mark next to the voting arrows. I hope to see more questions from you in the future!

Comment: Why you put est inside the brackets? Is 'est' change the meaning significantly?

Comment: @OldSport19 It's optional. It has no real effect on the meaning. Having it in is more explicit. I added a remark at the end of my answer.